# alasset showing wrong time

Tags: ios, alassetslibrary

```
[asset valueForProperty:ALAssetPropertyDate]);
```

is showing wrong time, its showing minutes correctly but hour is 5 less from current.

But my device is showing correct time in status bar.

Comment: i suggest ALAsset is not taking current time zone into account when setting / returning date

Comment: probably the time is in GMT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The call `[asset valueForProperty:ALAssetPropertyDate]` returns in NSDate. An NSDate object has the timeZone encoded in it.
To display an NSDate as NSString you should make use of an NSDateFormatter.

```
NSDate *date = [asset valueForProperty:ALAssetPropertyDate];

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [NSDateFormatter new];
[dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
[dateFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterNoStyle];
NSString *dateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];


[dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterNoStyle];
[dateFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
NSString *timeString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
```